# How to make my automatic image carousel loop back to the first image without exposing the second one

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on an Image carousel and it appears that I have ran into a problem. The carousel(there are three images) works well automatically but instead of it looping back to the first image, it goes all the way back to the first one exposing the second image for a brief moment. How could I get the carousel to make a complete loop without it exposing the second image in the process? Here is my code.

HTML

```
...<div class="carousel-container">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-left" id="prevBtn"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" id="nextBtn"></i>
    <div class="carousel-slide">
        <img src="./img/testpic3.jpg" id="lastClone" alt="">
        <img src="./img/testpic1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="./img/testpic2.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="./img/testpic3.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="./img/testpic1.jpg" id="firstClone" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
const carouselSlide = document.querySelector('.carousel-slide');
const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide img');


const prevBtn = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');


let counter = 1;
const size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;

carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-carouselImages[0].clientWidth * counter) + 'px)';

var interval = 5000;
setInterval(function() {
    var offset = counter % (carouselImages.length - 2);
    carouselImages[counter].id === 'firstClone';
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-carouselImages[0].clientWidth * counter) + 'px)';
    counter++;


    if (offset == 0) counter = 1; // to reset counter so next and prev button should work 

}, interval);

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (counter >= carouselImages.length - 1) return;
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    counter++;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-carouselImages[0].clientWidth * counter) + 'px)';
    // console.log(counter);

});
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (counter <= 0) return;
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    counter--;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-carouselImages[0].clientWidth * counter) + 'px)';
    // console.log(counter);
});



carouselSlide.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    console.log(carouselImages[counter]);
    if (carouselImages[counter].id === 'lastClone') {
        carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
        counter = carouselImages.length - 2;
        carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

    }
    if (carouselImages[counter].id === 'firstClone') {
        carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
        counter = carouselImages.length - counter;
        carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
    }

});
```

JavaScript:

```
const carouselSlide = document.querySelector('.carousel-slide');
const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide img');


const prevBtn = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');


let counter = 1;
const size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;

carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-carouselImages[0].clientWidth * counter) + 'px)';

var interval = 5000;
setInterval(function() {
var offset = counter % (carouselImages.length - 2);
carouselImages[counter].id === 'firstClone';
carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-carouselImages[0].clientWidth * counter) + 'px)';
counter++;


if (offset == 0) counter = 1; // to reset counter so next and prev button should work 
}, interval);

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
if (counter >= carouselImages.length - 1) return;
carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-carouselImages[0].clientWidth * counter) + 'px)';
// console.log(counter);

});
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
if (counter <= 0) return;
carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
counter--;
//carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-carouselImages[0].clientWidth * counter) + 'px)';
// console.log(counter);
});



carouselSlide.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
console.log(carouselImages[counter]);
if (carouselImages[counter].id === 'lastClone') {
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
    counter = carouselImages.length - 2;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
}
if (carouselImages[counter].id === 'firstClone') {
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
    counter = carouselImages.length - counter;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
}
```

});

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest your codes look complicated. You can simply use this.

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

With this, your carousel will loop everytime it reaches the end of your carousel. Or you can check the example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_carousel.asp).